# Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0C2z.jpg)

I have try to hit API then this type of error is occurs -  org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient

Comment: please click on enter image description here link above

Comment: You need the jar in your classpath.

Comment: I have already added this dependency inside pom.xml

Comment: also added in classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError means that the class was available while compiling but not able to find the definition at run time. 
Try by upgrading your httpclient depedency,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And then run `clean install`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the dependency for apache http components based on the tool you are using. Follow this link [dependency for apache http components][1]https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/dependency-info.html 
to add the dependency.

Comment: Try by upgrading your httpclient depedency And then run clean install

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.3</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an Apache commons dependency.

Realized it was because the dependency scope was set to `provided`, which was no longer viable, so changing the scope to `compile` fixed the issue for me.

For reference: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependency-scopes